# Jasmine Failure- TypeError: string is not a function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angularjs-filter

I've been trying to write a Jasmine test for a small JavaScript file. This file defines an event for my application called 'EIS'. Before my Jasmine test even runs, I get a failure message in the Jasmine Specs Runner because it cannot read my filter correctly. I followed the easy instructions in this question:

[How to unit test a filter in AngularJS 1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094569/how-to-unit-test-a-filter-in-angularjs)

but it doesn't help because Jasmine will not even read the filter in my original javascript file. Here it is (with the title of eventModule.js):

```
var app = angular.module("eisViewerApp",['ngGrid', 'ngRoute']);

function EISEvent(type, name, source, rawXML, $filter) {
    var date = new Date();
    **this.timestamp = $filter('date')(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a");**
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
    this.source= source;
    this.rawXML = rawXML;
    this.payload = "";

    this.setRawXml = function(rawXML) {
        this.rawXML = rawXML;
    }
    this.setPayload = function(payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }
}
```

And here is the Jasmine failure description:

```
TypeError: string is not a function
at new EISEvent (http://localhost:8080/EISViewer/js/eventModule.js:21:41)
```

I didn't include all the js code but line 21 is the one with ** around it. My filter works when the application controller calls it in another javascript file. So maybe I need to include the controller and the 'EISEvent' function call in my Jasmine test? Here is my Jasmine test if it helps:

```
describe( "EISEvent", function(){
   var eisEvent;
   var fakeDate = '10/23/2012';
   var fakeFilter;
   //inject the filter to resolve the dependency
       beforeEach(function() {
          inject(function ($injector) {
          //mock the services here
          fakeFilter = $injector.get('$filter')('date');
          })
       });
       beforeEach( function(){
           eisEvent = new EISEvent( "L", "theName", "theSource", "<beginTag>somexml</beginTag>", fakeFilter);
       });

    it( "Should be initialized", function(){
       expect( eisEvent ).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `EISEvent` is expecting an instance of Angular's `$filter` service. But in the test, you are passing the actual date filter function (not the instance of the `$filter` service).

So modify the `beforeEach()` in your test:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    inject(function ($injector) {
    //mock the services here
    fakeFilter = $injector.get('$filter');
    })
});
```

To be pedantic, it's not really a "fakeFilter" as you've named the variable. You're retrieving the actual `$filter` service when you do: `$injector.get('$filter');`

When you pass the `$filter` service to your `EISEvent` class, the code in your test should then work just like in your application.

To clarify what the code in `EISEvent` is doing, let's break it apart.

Original code:

```
this.timestamp = $filter('date')(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a");
```

In the above, `$filter('date')` retrieves Angular's "date" filter function. And then `(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a")` executes that filter function passing in the `date` variable and the date format string.

Comment: It worked thank you! And I also appreciate the explanation cause now I understand it. I didn't know what was being passed into my test filter variable