# AngularJS 1.7 Module Injection For Tests Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jestjs

My AngularJS (1.7.x) application has a custom filter that I want to write tests around it, and I decided to use Jest to perform this task.

My main issue is that as I follow [this tutorial by Curt](https://curtistimson.co.uk/post/angularjs/angularjs-jest-unit-testing/), I am struggling to properly get the filter (which has no outside dependencies so I thought it was the prime target to introduce unit tests with) to load within the test harness.

For starters, here is a simplified version of the filter for the purpose of this question:

```
angular.module('app.module').filter('takeTheThing', () =>
  function (parameter1) {
    return `${parameter1} thing!`;
  }
);
```

And, after following the tutorial above, as well as reading up on [another SO question specific to testing AngularJS filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094569/how-to-unit-test-a-filter-in-angularjs-1-x), I have attempted every conceivable version of my simple test file as follows [but receive a cryptic error message from Angular about it](https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.6/docs/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=app.module&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.7.6%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dapp.module%0A%20%20%20%20at%20minErr%20(%2FUsers%2Fuser%2Fdev%2Fapp%2Fnode_modules%2Fangular%2Fangular.js:99:1)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20$injectorMinErr%20(%2FUsers%2Fuser%2Fdev%2Fapp%2Fnode_modules%2Fangular%2Fangular.js:2285:17)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20factory%20(%2FUsers%2Fuser%2Fdev%2Fapp%2Fnode_modules%2Fangular%2Fangular.js:2206:38)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ensure%20(%2FUsers%2Fuser%2Fdev%2Fapp%2Fnode_modules%2Fangular%2Fangular.js:2283:14)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20angularModule%20(%2FUsers%2Fuser%2Fdev%2Fapp%2Fnode_modules%2Fangular%2Fangular.js:5013:22)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20call%20(%2FUsers%2Fuser%2Fdev%2Fapp%2Fnode_modules%2Fangular%2Fangular.js:387:11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(%2FUsers%2Fuser%2Fdev%2Fapp%2Fnode_modules%2Fangular%2Fangular.js:4997:5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.loadModules%20%5Bas%20injector%5D%20(%2FUsers%2Fuser%2Fdev%2Fapp%2Fnode_modules%2Fangular%2Fangular.js:4914:19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.WorkFn%20(%2FUsers%2Fuser%2Fdev%2Fapp%2Fnode_modules%2Fangular-mocks%2Fangular-mocks.js:3449:52)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.asyncJestTest%20(%2FUsers%2Fuser%2Fdev%2Fapp%2Fnode_modules%2Fjest-jasmine2%2Fbuild%2Fjasmine_async.js:108:37)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20resolve%20(%2FUsers%2Fuser%2Fdev%2Fapp%2Fnode_modules%2Fjest-jasmine2%2Fbuild%2Fqueue_runner.js:56:12)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20new%20Promise%20(%3Canonymous%3E)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20mapper%20(%2FUsers%2Fuser%2Fdev%2Fapp%2Fnode_modules%2Fjest-jasmine2%2Fbuild%2Fqueue_runner.js:43:19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20promise.then%20(%2FUsers%2Fuser%2Fdev%2Fapp%2Fnode_modules%2Fjest-jasmine2%2Fbuild%2Fqueue_runner.js:87:41)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20%3Canonymous%3E%0A%20%20%20%20at%20process._tickCallback%20(internal%2Fprocess%2Fnext_tick.js:188:7)):

```
require('../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js');
require('../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js');

//Commenting or un-commenting this, results in module-related injector errors:
//require('./takeTheThing.filter.js');

describe('The thingerizer', () => {
  let $filter;
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app.module'));

  //Injecting this specifically, or _$filter_ still errors:
  beforeEach(inject(takeTheThingFilter => {
    $filter = takeTheThingFilter;
  }));

  //Injecting here instead of in the beforeEach, same issue
  it('should give me something', () => {
    //Calling the specific filter or thru the Angular $filter... Same
    const actual = $filter(1);

    expect(actual).toEqual('1 thing!');
  });
});
```

I'm pulling my hair out, but there's something quite basic I'm missing in regards to the test setup (specifically, how to load the app "correctly" without whole-hog loading my entire application). What gives?

AngularJS: 1.7.5

Angular Mocks: 1.7.6

Jest: 23.6.0 (I am using `gulp-jest` but even when I directly call `jest` from within the `bin` folder, I get the exact same errors, so I omitted most of those details here)

Comment: I've seen that using a different version of mocks from Angular causes issue, but even when I pull mocks back to 1.7.5, I am still seeing issues here. Even as I see that both Angular and Mocks are loaded, I can successfully call `angular.mock.module()` and yet when I load the SUT, Angular complains about an unregistered module.

Comment: For now, I am abandoning this quest, because even as I switched to the Karma test runner using the Karma-Jasmine plugin (and the Babel preprocessor), I ended up receiving the same errors. There must be issue with my specific project structure and build setup that is causing issue with unit testing AngularJS. If I return and solve this in the future, I'll be sure to return and detail the solution.